# VBScript - Verify input is IP, 3-digits per octet

Tags: error-handling, vbscript, ip-address, custom-error-handling

I am a student learning VBScript.  It was only a few days ago [grin], that I cut my teeth on programming in BASIC, DOS and Machine Code, so the basic concepts are not foreign, it has just been a bit.

***Caveat - this is part of a graded assignment, guidance and understanding of the code is what is mainly being requested.***

Trying to write a script for user input of IP address where each octet is in 3-digit format (leading zeros if necessary).  This is the starting input

```
' Get IP address to convert
WScript.StdOut.Write("Please Enter your IP address (3 digits per octet) -> ")
strIP = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine()
```

Trying to get the error-checking and having problems.  Tried various ways but none seem to offer the desired output, if not fail with various VBScript errors when run.

Version 1:

```
Dim sMatch(15)
if sMatch = strIP Like "###.###.###.###" Then
   Wscript.Echo "The strings are equal."
Else
   Wscript.Echo "The strings are not equal."
' WScript.Echo sMatch
End If
```

Version 2:

```
String str = StrComp("strIP", ""\###.\###.\###.\###"",vbTextCompare)
If str < 0 or str > 0 then WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "Improper IP format."
```

Version 3:

```
iFirstOct = Left(strIP,3)

z1 = strComp(iFirstOct, "###", 1)
WScript.Echo "z1 -> " & z1
WScript.Echo "IP -> " & iFirstOct
If z1 < 1 or z1 > 1 Then 
  WScript.Echo " Error in input !" 
  WScript.quit
End If
```

I sort of like Version 3 as I can subroutine this, but not sure which is a viable option.  Any assistance to identify where I am erroring, and how, will be appreciated.

***Caveat - this is part of a graded assignment, guidance and understanding of the code is what is mainly being requested.***

-- Edit - 16-FEB-21 --

Étienne,

Here is the final script. I have run the different error scenario's and it appears to function the way I need it to.  Thank you for your assistance.

```
' IP_func.vbs
'
'  By: Étienne Laneville
'    Minor modifications by DragonRider
'  From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66177237/vbscript-verify-input-is-ip-3-digits-per-octet
'
'
WScript.StdOut.Write("Please Enter your IP address (3 digits per octet) -> ")
strIP = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine()
WScript.Echo vbCrLf & " Input -> " & vbTab & strIP & vbCrlf

' Call error-checking function
CheckIP(strIP)


Function CheckIP(strIP)
    Dim arrOctets
    Dim iCounter
    Dim sOctet
    
    ' Check for periods
    If InStr(strIP, ".") = 0 Then
        CheckIP = False
        WScript.Echo " Incorrect number of octets. Please try again."
        Exit Function 
    End If

    ' Split string on periods
    arrOctets = Split(strIP, ".")
    
    ' Check that correct number of octets has been received
    If UBound(arrOctets) <> 3 Then
        CheckIP = False
        WScript.Echo " Incorrect number of octets. Please try again."
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' Check each octet
    For iCounter = 1 To 4
        
        sOctet = arrOctets(iCounter - 1)
        
        ' Check if it's numeric
        If Not IsNumeric(sOctet) Then
            CheckIP = False
            WScript.Echo " Improper IP Address. Please try again."
            Exit Function
        End If
        
        ' Check if 3 digits
'        Dim three As String
        If Not Len(sOctet) = 3 Then
            CheckIP = False
            WScript.Echo " 3-Digits per octet. Please try again."
            Exit Function
        End If
        
        ' Check for proper values
        If CInt(sOctet) > 255 Then
            CheckIP = False
            WScript.Echo " Octet out of range. Please try again."
            Exit Function
        End If
        
        If CInt(sOctet) < 0 Then
            CheckIP = False
            WScript.Echo " Improper IP Address. Please try again."
            Exit Function
        End If
        
    Next
        
    CheckIP = True

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple function that breaks things down into simple operations:

```
Function CheckIP(strIP)
    Dim arrOctets
    Dim iCounter
    Dim sOctet
    
    ' Check for periods
    If InStr(strIP, ".") = 0 Then
        CheckIP = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Split string on periods
    arrOctets = Split(strIP, ".")
    
    ' Check that correct number of octets has been received
    If UBound(arrOctets) <> 3 Then
        CheckIP = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' Check each octet
    For iCounter = 1 To 4
        
        sOctet = arrOctets(iCounter - 1)
        
        ' Check if it's numeric
        If Not IsNumeric(sOctet) Then
            CheckIP = False
            Exit Function
        End If
        
        ' Check for proper values
        If CInt(sOctet) > 255 Then
            CheckIP = False
            Exit Function
        End If
        
        If CInt(sOctet) < 0 Then
            CheckIP = False
            Exit Function
        End If
        
    Next
        
    CheckIP = True

End Function
```

Comment: WOW!  I can read and understand this, all pretty straight forward.
 As we have not covered many of these commands in class, I am sure I would have difficulty passing this off as "my work".  Although, I might be able to add portions to what I already have.
 Many thanks for the reply

Comment: With a function like this you can return a message explaining the exact problem with the IP address, like "3rd octet cannot be greater than 255".

Comment: I ran this code adding my "Get IP address to convert" section, did not get anything out.  Tried putting Echo commands of the variables in various places and only "strIP" ever gave any output, all the other variables were blank.  Even tried using out-of-range numbers (+260) for the various positions, still no errors and 'strIP" repeated the input string.
  If I am missing something, I do not know what as the code appears to terminate normally, with no errors.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you tried? This is a function that will simply return `true` or `false` depending on the validity of the IP address. It will not change `strIP`.

Comment: Figured out my problem... I did not "call" the function.  I did add the section to check for 3-digits per octet, (thank you for leaving that for me to figure out).  I also added error responses.

Comment: You can even specify which octet is problematic in your error messages: `WScript.Echo " Octet #" & iCounter & " (" & sOctet & ") out of range (0-255). Please try again."`

Answer (score 1):

You can also check the validity of an IP Address using Regular Expression with this function :

```
Option Explicit
Dim  Title,IP
Title = "Test the validity of an IP address"
IP = InputBox("Please enter an IP Address",Title,"172.16.18.21")
If Is_Valid(IP) = True Then
    MsgBox IP & " is a Valid IP Address",64,Title
Else
    MsgBox IP & " is Not a Valid IP Address",16,Title
End if
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function Is_Valid(ip)
    Dim RegularExpressionObject
    Set RegularExpressionObject = New RegExp
    With RegularExpressionObject
        .Pattern = "^((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d?\d)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d?\d)$"
        .IgnoreCase = False
        If .Test(ip)= True then
            Is_Valid = True
        end if
    End With
End Function
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Running your code with no modifications does identify good/bad IP addresses.
  Unfortunately, even after spending a few hours on it, I have been unsuccessful in understanding all of your code, thus would not be able to explain it to my Professor.
  Additionally, need to avoid “MsgBox” and have to have verify IP address contains 3 digits per octet as these need to be broken-out in another part of the program, thus the "Please Enter your IP address (3 digits per octet)“ and “iFirstOct = Left(strIP,3)”.